# Blacklist filename on FreeBSD ZFS

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, zfs

I have a ZFS based NAS that various platforms use for shared storage, namely Windows XP/7/8 and Linux.

I've noticed that Windows clients are creating Thumbs.db files left right and centre, which I do not want. It may seem extreme but I'd like to blacklist the creating of these files on the storage server. Presumably it's possible to tell Windows to stop trying to create them in the first place, but it will only take single glance at a directory before a yet to be configured client generates another one.

Is it possible to blacklist files being created on a FS based on the name? Does anyone foresee a problem in doing this (software will not be installed in these exports)?

Some advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can forsee is that opening each NAS folder on Windows will take longer because there's no Thumbs.db to get an icon cache, and it will try to write that cache file anyway so it will have to process a write error. It shouldn't be ridiculously longer, but it may be noticeable in some circumstances.

As for being able to blacklist? I have no idea, though if it is possible, I'd love to get updated and told how to do so myself.

Comment: Well as regards the delay, most machines should be configured not to try and cache thumbnails, so there should be no error in writing the thumbs file. For the most case, too, I have configured machines to load all directories in the 'details' view. I think this view does not trigger thumbs generation.